# Assigning string to pointers

Tags: c

By definition, in C, a string is an array of characters

```
int main() {
 char *name="David Bolton"; 
 printf("My name is %s\r\n",name) ;

 return 0;
 }
```

The line `char * name="David Bolton";` defines name as a pointer to the first character in the string i.e 'D' .So ,the pointer name should hold address but it prints 'David Bolton' why?What is the reason ?Since it only holds the address of D why is it printing the whole string?

Comment: Always take a look at the man pages. It would have given you the answer you needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you use `%s`, C will know that you want to print a string, so, it will print character by character to screen, until it meets symbol `\0`.

Comment: but name is a pointer not a string ,and has address in it.I m new to c

Comment: when you use `%s`, C will "understand" that you want print a string. A string is made by characters. a character is 2 bytes. so, it will use the address of first character to know which character, in this case is `name` and print it, and plus 2 bytes, and continues to print it. until it meets null bytes.

Comment: The `%s` specifier is telling `printf` to be clever, and print the string at the address which `name` points to, rather than the actual pointer value of `name`.

Comment: @hqt Nitpick: The ending byte is `\0`, not `\o`.

Comment: @michaelb958 ah. i look o likes O. yes, it's `zero` thanks, I have edited :)

Answer (score 3):

The `%s` format specifier instructs `printf` to treat the data pointed to as an array of chars that are terminated by a null (zero) byte.  Use `%p` if you want to print the pointer address instead.

Comment: but name is a pointer that has an address of D,even if it prints it should print D.Plz help i m new to c programming and i m really getting headache on this problem

Comment: `name` is a pointer to the string literal `"David Bolton"`.  This string literal will be stored at a linker-determined address in memory.  The address stored in `name` points to the first byte of the string literal.

Answer (score 2):

In the `printf` format string, the `%s` specifier assumes that the corresponding argument is a pointer to the character data. Which is exactly what `name` is.

Comment: but name is pointing to D and even if it prints ,it should print D as it has no address of other characters

Comment: It does know the address of the other characters; they are immediately following the `D` in memory! It stops printing when it hits the end-of-string marker which is a `0` byte.

Answer (score 2):

String in C language is made to determine that a 0-terminated.

"David Bolton"

memory image : David Bolton\0
So it is possible to address pointing displays a guide to the location of 0 in the address area.

E.g.)

```
void print_string(char *string){
    while('\0'!=*string){
        putchar(*string++);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html) prints from the address given to it. Because `%s` is used to print a string, it gets the start address from `name` and prints till it reaches `\0` . If you do `printf("%p",name)` it will give you the address stored in `name` i.e. of `D`.

See [this](http://boredzo.org/pointers/) to read about pointers and [this](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm) for arrays